# Are these animal droppings?

Tags: animal-identification

Here's another early springtime find in some woods of Central NY State (April 19th, snow mostly gone but only the earliest plants flowering or leafing).

A pretty large pile of what could be animal droppings? Looks like balled up hair. Right on the trail. Approx 12" / 30cm across.

I think this is much too large for owl pellets... and seemed pretty uniform in composition.

Is it droppings? If so, what predator / prey? If not, what is it?

[image]

Comment: Might be a [pellet](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gew%C3%B6lle_Maulwurf.jpeg). Did you notice any bones?

Comment: @no, did not, which was one of the reasons I thought a pellet was less likely, aside from the size.

Comment: Did  you open one up?

Comment: @WeatherVane we poked around a bit, and it all seemed fairly homogenous.

Comment: Could be hair-balls from a big cat (cougar?) or droppings from a similar animal after eating something with lots of hair/fur?

Comment: It's too big to be hairballs and it's missing the vomit. Very likely droppings, possibly coyote or similar.

Comment: A pellet doesn't necessarily contain bones. Pellet just means the hair ball was ejected out front instead of going out back. My dog can produce pellets that are almost the size of his heaps (diameter-wise, he probably could produce the same size volume-wise as well, but so far, he never got that much furry stuff).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Most likely from a coyote.  They eat everything but cant digest the hair. I've seen some mountain lion poop look like that also.

Comment: This was certainly in a coyote friendly area. Mountain lions... not so much as far as I know.

Comment: agreed, looks like coyote scat to me as well.  They pass hair after they eat a critter.  And they also like to do so on well traveled paths and such to mark territory.